# How can i get perfect matching texture to part of sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm new in Three.js. I'm working on spherical panorama using three.js and i have got problem with matching. I would like to get matching separate texture to original sphere. At the moment I'm trying resolve my problem by using `PlaneGeometry` object with texture applied and manually updating position of them, but it seems to me that this is bad idea.. The sphere is curved, against plane.

Additionaly, would like to tell you that, I have calculated center point on my original 2D image (image on sphere) and points (p1,p2,p3,p4).

[image]

This is my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eukfLop5/)

Could you help me and indicate correct way? Is a geometry plane can be perfectly matching ?